# How do i access variable of void method of other class from another class

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

```
  Code of Broweserselection.java 


    @SuppressWarnings("serial")
        class Browserselection extends JFrame implements ActionListener
        { 
         public void BrowserSelection1()
         { Some code...}

         @Override
         public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
         {
           WebDriver d1 = null;

           if(FireFox.isSelected())
            {
             dispose();
             System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver","driverPath");
             d1 = new  FirefoxDriver();
            }

          this.setDriver(d1);
         }

        public WebDriver setDriver(WebDriver driver)
        {
          this.driver2 = driver;
          this.getDriver();

          return this.driver2;
        }

        public WebDriver getDriver()
        {
          return this.driver2;          
        }

===========================================================================

Code of MyMainClass.java

    public class MyMainClass{

        public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException, IOException {

            Browserselection bs= new Browserselection();
            bs.BrowserSelection1();
            WebDriver driver=bs.getDriver();
            System.out.println(driver + "Hello from main");
```

1. here driver shows `null` value while i need to access of value of `Browserselection.java`'s `getDriver` method's value. I do `println` `Browserselection.java` has proper value while in `MyMainClass.java` `bs.getDriver()`; shows `null`.
2. is there any way to access d1 variable of actionPerformed nethod's if condition from MyMainClass?

I am new to Java and learning selenium.

Comment: Have you ever called the setDriver()? What is the code inBrowserSelection1() method ? What is the meaning of the call this.getDriver(); inside set driver?

Comment: @AmitBera  in BrowserSelection1() I am using radiobutton group for user input in jFrame and based on that public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) is called. That is working properly.

Comment: As per your code driver can be set either calling `actionPerformed()` or  `setDriver()` method call but I can't see you never called them in your code before `bs.getDriver()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Issue is not in drived selection. it is in architecture of your code.
see below code might help you.

```
@SuppressWarnings("serial")
    class Browserselection extends JFrame implements ActionListener
    { 
     public void BrowserSelection1(String selectedBrower)
     { 
         WebDriver d1 = null;

        if(selectedBrower.equals("firefox")){
            d1 = new  FirefoxDriver();  
        }else if(selectedBrower.equals("firefox")){
            d1 = new  ChromeDriver();   
        }
     }
     /*  
      As per this code , your input from user will be received in this method
     */
     @Override
     public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
     {
       String driverSelected = "";
        if(FireFox.isSelected()){
            driverSelected =  "firefox";
        }else if(Chrome.isSelected()){
            driverSelected =  "chrome";
        }
        Browserselection bs= new Browserselection();
        bs.BrowserSelection1(driverSelected);

     }
}
```

Main method will be used for just start your project, so no need to create object of Browserselection class in main method, rather create that class object where it actually require.

Hope this will help you.

Answer (score 1):

Use this method :

```
public WebDriver getDriver()
    {
      driver2 = new ChromeDriver();
      return this.driver2;          
    }
```

Note that you have to declare the driver2 in your class like :   `private WebDriver driver2;`

Your whole class would look like this :

```
public class Browserselection {

   private WebDriver driver2;

    public void BrowserSelection1()
     {
        //some code 
     }

     @Override
     public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
     {
       WebDriver d1 = null;

       if(FireFox.isSelected())
        {
         dispose();
         System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver","driverPath");
         d1 = new  FirefoxDriver();
        }

      this.setDriver(d1);
     }

    public WebDriver setDriver(WebDriver driver)
    {
      this.driver2 = driver;
      this.getDriver();

      return this.driver2;
    }

    public WebDriver getDriver()
    {
      driver2 = new ChromeDriver();
      return this.driver2;          
    }

}
```